# Python time series graph not plotting y values correctly

Tags: python, time-series

I have this data frame:

| Year | production | imports |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2003 | 2,061,995 | $55,812,008,171 |
| 2004 | 1,991,394 | $78,277,321,635 |
| 2005 | 1,892,095 | $107,478,346,132 |
| 2006 | 1,856,340 | $131,528,352,871 |
| 2007 | 1,851,974 | $147,375,398,002 |

I plotted both lines with this code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([(2003, '2,061,995', '$55,812,008,171'), 
                   (2004, '1,991,394', '$78,277,321,635'), 
                   (2005, '1,892,095', '$107,478,346,132'), 
                   (2006, '1,856,340', '$131,528,352,871'), 
                   (2007, '1,851,974', '$147,375,398,002')],
                  columns=['Year', 'production', 'imports'])


def plot_df(df, x, y, title="", xlabel='Year', ylabel='US Domestic Crude Oil Production', dpi=100):
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,4), dpi=dpi)
    plt.plot(x, y, color='tab:red')
    plt.gca().set(title=title, xlabel=xlabel, ylabel=ylabel)
    plt.show()

plot_df(df, x=df['Year'], y=df['production'], title='US Domestic Crude Oil Production')
```

It is plotting a linear regression with the Y-axis being the exact Y-values in the data points, rather than time series. The graph with this code shows a positive, straight line when it should show the dips and peaks of production over time.

[image]

How can I make this a time series graph rather than a linear regression?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I added a picture of what you get. Please infirm or confirm that this is what you get (and therefore that the dataframe is as I've surmised it in my previous edit)

Answer (score 0):

Please, include a minimal reproducible example. Including imports. And minimal data in the code. I did it for you so as an example of what it means: anybody can now just cut and past your code and see the problem by themselves, and then try to correct it (I had to work way more to reformat your question so that it can be answered, than I did to actually find the problem).

As for the problem, it is very simple: those are not numbers. 2nd field contains commas. And 3rd one currency units.
Matplotlib cannot guess how it is supposed to order those. They are just string label from its perspective.

Just reuse, without modification, your `plot_df` function with this dataframe instead,

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([(2003, 2061995, '$55,812,008,171'), (2004, 1991394, '$78,277,321,635'), (2005, 1892095, '$107,478,346,132'), (2006, 1856340, '$131,528,352,871'), (2007, 1851974, '$147,375,398,002')], columns=['Year', 'production', 'imports'])
```

And you get this, which is, I am pretty sure, closer to what you expected.
[image]

Note, that what you got was not a linear regression. It was just plotting labels (years, as string as well I guess, but unique anyway) against labels (production strings). With all labels being unique, it gives a quite boring plot indeed.